how to keep SRP (single responsiblity pattern) in nestjs
I have the below scenerio, I could complete it simply calling each responsible service within other services but this will violate the SRP.
its a post method accessed via /organization.
when user send request to this method, I must do the following tasks in the same pattern:

create organization (its a separate module with own repisitory)
create a user (same)
assign user to organization (same)
send email to user (separate module)

How do I handle this in the organization controller as soon as the request is received? I dont want to inject the UserService inside the OrganizationService and so on for the rest of them.
I am a developer with few months of experience in NestJS and this is bothering me.
I have alread done it this way (psudo code):
OrganizationController {
/organization
saveOrganization(body){

const org = this.organizationService.create(body)
const user = this.userService.create(org.id)
const orgUser = this.orgUserService.create(user.id,org.id)
triggerEvent('user.created',{payload})

}}


What exactly is bothering you and why is there a problem with SRP? I am not sure what do you want. Why calling each responsible service within other services will validate SRP?

it will *invalidate  SRP. because one service will be doing many things. What bothering me is that what is the right approach to handle the mentioned task?

It sounds like you're describing one logical operation which by definition involves performing a number of more granular logical operations. If you don't want to couple the organization and user services create a third service which injects both of them. That's effectively what you're doing in the controller currently. Alternately, just write a function. This is JavaScript after all and classes have made the language a mess.
